# Ajax.Begin is re submitting the whole page with MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am puzzled with MVC 5 Ajax.Begin form. I used it in the past many time without any issues.

Common problem is that developers forget to include jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js file but not in this case.

I enabled in webconfig in appSetting section:

```
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
 <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

I included 3 files.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

I even set Layout to null to make sure none of other js files are interrupting.

```
<div id="contactSection">

</div>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendContact", "Home", new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "contactSection" }))
        {
    <fieldset>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label >Full Name *</label>

                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.contactVM.fullName, new { @class = "form-control",  })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label >E-mail Address *</label>

                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.contactVM.email, new { @class = "form-control", type = "email" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label >Phone</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.contactVM.phone, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <label >Subject *</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.contactVM.subject, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label >Message *</label>

                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.contactVM.message, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "10000", rows = "8" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            </div>
                        </div>
}
```

In controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult SendContact(MainVM vModel)
    {
        vModel.contactVM.success = true;
        return PartialView("_ContactResults", vModel.contactVM);

    }
```

and finally partial view

```
@if (Model.success)
{
 <!-- Alert Success -->
<div id="alert_success" class="alert alert-success margin-bottom-30">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-   hidden="false">&times;</button>
    <strong>Thank You!</strong> Your message was successfully sent! As long it was not spam, we will get back to you asap.
    </div><!-- /Alert Success -->
 }
   else
{
<!-- Alert Failed -->
   <div id="alert_failed" class="alert alert-danger margin-bottom-30">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-  hidden="false">&times;</button>
        <strong>[SMTP] Error!</strong> Sorry something went wrong, try again please!
</div><!-- /Alert Failed -->
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is your element with `id="contactSection"`?

Comment: Top of the document.

Comment: are you sure that js files are loaded correct?

Comment: I came across this issue before. This will occur when ajax-min js rendered twice.

Comment: OP has also not specified UpdateMode, though that should not be an issue

Comment: Yes, js files are loaded correctly.

Comment: Nothing is loaded twice.

Comment: Try adding

 new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,  OnBegin = " function name", OnSuccess = " function name" }

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem.
In console I was getting this error - Uncaught TypeError: a(...).live is not a function.
From what I remember live function in jquery has been deprecated long time ago.
When I installed initially nuget package Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax it installed version 2.0.20710 - which is quite old. I have to reinstall nuget package and force it to download version 3.2.3